# Build a tree using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js object that contains hierarchical data, and I want to represent it using a tree or something like **how windows do with it's folders in the exploring panel**.

[image]

Is there any JQuery library that could help me doing this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com). It's cross-browser compatible back to IE8

[Treeview](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/) also looks right, but it's lacking support (the last commit was over a year ago). On their website, they recommend jsTree.

Answer (score 0):

You will easy get a javascript api and js, i was get help before use in my java tiles project
visit http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/